# Scope resolution in C

Tags: c

I'm mallocing an int and an array inside a if condition. Like this

```
if(type == 1){
        int connectionCount = 0;
        struct sockaddr_in** IpList = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in*)*256);
        for (int i = 0; i <256; ++i)
        {
            IpList[i] =  malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) * 256);
        }
    }
```

Subsequently I'm trying to access the same variables inside another if

```
if(type == 1){
     sockClient = accept(sockServer, (struct sockaddr*)&remoteaddr, &addrlen);
         if(sockClient < 0){
           perror("Accept failed: ");
         }else{
            FD_SET(sockClient, &master);
            if(sockClient > fdmax){
             fdmax = sockClient;
         }
         IpList[connectionCount] = remoteaddr;
         connectionCount++;

         //send list to all connections in list
       }//end of else
   }
```

I get the following compilation errors

```
:108:13: warning: unused variable 'connectionCount' [-Wunused-variable]
        int connectionCount = 0;
            ^
:184:49: error: use of undeclared identifier 'connectionCount'
                            for (int i = 0; i < connectionCount; ++i)
                                                ^
:186:62: error: use of undeclared identifier 'IpList'
                               struct sockaddr_in tempSock = IpList[i];
                                                             ^
:220:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'IpList'
                                IpList[connectionCount] = remoteaddr;
                                ^
:220:40: error: use of undeclared identifier 'connectionCount'
                                IpList[connectionCount] = remoteaddr;
                                       ^
:221:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'connectionCount'
                                connectionCount++;
```

Comment: And your question is?.. You can try to declare your variable as `volatile int` to get rid of these errors.

Comment: You need to go back to learn the basics of C, and especially the scoping rules and variable life-time. Short answer is that `IpList` and `connectionCount` are local inside the block they are defined in, any other `IpList` or `connectionCount` variables are different variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the declarations of the variables to the top of the function or to the scope that is higher than the two `if` statements.

```
int connectionCount = 0;
struct sockaddr_in** IpList = NULL;
```

and set the value of `IpList` under the first `if` block:

```
IpList = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in*)*256);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `int connectionCount = 0;` in inside first if , so you can not access it outside `if` , because it's scope is limited to first `if` only. You need to see [scope rule.](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-rules-in-c/)

Answer (score 0):

`struct sockaddr_in** IpList` needs to be declared in a scope (`{} block) that encloses the both`if`statements. In C the scoping rules are easy: a declaration is visible inside the outmost`{}` block and all contained blocks. Example:

```
{
     int x;
     if(condition) {
       x = ...; // x is referencing the enclosing block/scope
     } else {
       int y;   // y is only available in this block/scope
       x = ...; // x is referencing the enclosing block/scope
     }
}
```

Note that you may at any time override the access to a name by shadowing it with a closer declaration:

```
{
     int x;
     if(condition) {
       x = ...; // x is referencing the enclosing block/scope
     } else {
       int x;   // This x shadows the outer x
       x = ...; // x is referencing this enclosing block/scope
     }
}
```